# AutoLsip - Update Command Window Text on Exsisting Line

Tags: cad, autolisp

There's this Whirl function that I found interesting while learning from this [lsp file](https://github.com/yyxuxyy/autolisp/blob/master/DrawExcel.lsp). The problem I'm having is that although `(princ "\010")` should be removing and replacing the last character shown, my cad application (*DraftSight*) is simply either ignoring the command, or it doesn't know how to interpret the command. How can I update the text in the command window without going to the next line?

```
(defun Whirl ()
  (if *Whirl#
    (setq *Whirl# (1+ *Whirl#))
    (setq *Whirl# 1)
  );if
  (if (>= *Whirl# 5)
    (setq *Whirl# 1)
  );if
  (cond
    ((= *Whirl# 1)(princ "-"))
    ((= *Whirl# 2)(princ "\\"))
    ((= *Whirl# 3)(princ "|"))
    ((= *Whirl# 4)(princ "/"))
  );cond
  (princ "\010")
);defun Whirl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `"\r"` will remove everything before it that's on the same line as itself. Therefore,

```
(princ "Test01 \nTest02 \rTest03")(princ)
```

will return:

```
Test01 
Test03
```

This means that the entire line will need to be rewritten instead of just the last character, but that won't be much of a problem for me.